# What features should I look for in a trail camera?

Tags: photography, trail-cameras

Trail cameras are motioned achieved cameras that are used to capture pictures of wild animals in the outdoors. The idea is that you can set it up in a place where animals are like to be such as a trail and the camera will take the pictures as they pass.

What **features in a trail camera should I look for?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As with anything, features can depend on intended usage.

Beyond the basics of weatherproofing, battery life, onboard storage capacity, the convenience of battery changing, mounting options, etc. I'd consider:

- **Night vision** - a lot of animal activity happens at night, so a good night vision camera is key
- **Sensitivity** - do you only want big animals, or anything that'll trip a basic PIR switch?
- **Timer mode** - to conserve batteries/storage - do you only want the camera to operate between certain hours (sunrise/sunset periods, for example)?
- **Video** - do you want moving as well as static pictures?
- **3G/4G connectivity** - automatically upload content to cloud servers?
- **Security** - do you need to protect the camera from passers-by/rockfalls/hangry bears?
- **Environmental impact** - does the design/colouration/placement of the camera adversely affect subjects or the environment in which it's placed?

Comment: "hangry" is the a combination of hungry and angry?

Comment: @JamesJenkins It is.  I know what the word means, so I guess it's widely known.

Comment: Oh wow, it is a real word, [Hangry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/hangry-meaning) I thought it was a typo!

Comment: It seemed to be an applicable word for bears...